# How to locate pixels and bands of image in R

Tags: r

the format is tiff
I have read a tiff image and plot it
how to locate pixels and bands of this image now

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Your question is quite broad. Have you tried anything?

Comment: There is just not enough information as to what you are after and what you have tried. Are you wanting to subset pixels based on a query? Locating bands just makes no sense.

Comment: can you show me how to locate subset pixels based on a query first

Comment: I would suggest you read [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf). There are methods as.vector, as.array and as.raster from which you can use matrix subsetting. I am sure there are other ways.

Answer (score 1):

"Locating pixels" can assume many meanings so, I am just taking a guess at what you are after. I recommend using the raster package as this will keep the problem memory safe and provide a number of functions specific to operating on raster arrays.

Let's create some data (note; you can use "raster" or "stack" to read raster format files on disk).

```
require(raster)
r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
  r[] <- runif(100)
    plot(r)
```

Here is an example of an "interactive" query of pixel values from a plot.

```
pxy <- locator(1) # click on plot where you want to query pixel value
  extract(r, cbind(pxy$x, pxy$y)) # returns value associated with click query
```

You can also apply a query to subset a raster. There are many ways to do this in the raster package. Here are two simple examples that set values < 0.5 to NA.

```
# not memory safe
r05 <- r
  r05[r05 < 0.5] <- NA 
    plot(r05)

# Memory safe, can specify out raster with "filename" argument
r05 <- calc(r, fun=function(x) { x[x < 0.5] <- NA; return(x) })
  plot(r05)
```

If you need x,y "locations" you can use "rasterToPoints" to return x, y, value. There are a number of "cellFrom" functions that will return the cell row/column or index.

```
rasterToPoints(r, spatial=FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, now I have checked the attributes of the image I read, and it shows > attributes(t)
$dim
[1] 285 297   8, I just want to locate a pixel and check with ArcGIS, do you know the command to locate pixels in this situation?

Comment: What package are you using? I still do not understand "locate a pixel". Using what criteria? Do want the value of a specific row/column? Obviously, we are not understanding what you are after yet, you keep repeating the exact same question!